# How to set permissions after Jenkins GIT deployment

Tags: git, deployment, jenkins, centos, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the GIT plugin in Jenkins to deploy a few websites to my CentOS server. This works great pretty much out of the box. The only thing I'm missing is that I want to set the permissions on certain folders (like upload folders) to something else after deployment.

What is the best way to go about that? I have used phing in other projects and that works great with a custom shell script. However, I'd like to avoid using phing just to set the permissions right on my folders. If possible, I'd like to do it in the GIT job itself, but I'm not sure that's possible with jenkins.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Git 'remembers' permissions - users, groups etc will be different on the different machines it is installed on anyway.
Do you have SSH from Jenkins to the server or is Jenkins running on the server? If that is the case you could issue some (remote) bash chmod commands.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in Simon. Jenkins is running on the server itself (as it is a local dev/QA machine). Should I issue a separate bash command in a new jenkins job? If so, can you point me to the right kind of job to issue?

Comment: When configuring the job choose 'Add build step' and then 'execute shell'. Use the help function next to the Command field (the question mark) for info on how to run other shells instead of default /bin/sh